# Binding a table view to an array of dictionaries

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSTableView`, and I've used Interface Builder to bind its **Content** to an instance of an `NSArrayController` subclass. I have **Controller Key** set to `arrangedObjects`.

So far so good: If I just load an array of strings into my `NSArrayController` (using `addObjects)` and leave the **Model Key Path** blank, those strings show up in the table.

However, if I add an array of dictionaries to my `NSArrayController`, such that each dictionary has a `name` property, and I set **Model Key Path** to `name`, the table just shows a stringified version of the entire `arrangedObjects` array *n* times, where *n* is the length of the array. Indeed, this happens no matter whether **Model Key Path** is set to `name`, `foo`, or blank.

I just want the `NSTableView` to display the `name` property of each dictionary in `arrangedObjects`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: In addition to binding the aforementioned `NSTableView`'s **Content** (which turned out to be irrelevant), I'd bound the corresponding `NSTableColumn`'s **Value** to have the controller `arrangedObjects`, with no **Model Key Path**. Setting that to `name` made everything work fine.

Comment: Hi Trevor, I am running into the same problem you described above. In my case I have an array of dictionaries. I bound the array to arraycontroller in IB using Binding Inspector -> Controller contents and click on Bind to and point to File's owner. Then I went to NSTableColumn's Value to "Array controller". The Controller Key reads "arrangedObjects" and in Model Key Path I set it as "Path" which is key in the nsdictionary. Finally in NSTextField inside TableCellView I bind value to TableCellView with model Key path as objectValue. I get garbage. I dont know whats happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You are almost right. At the end, you said you bound the NSTextField inside your TableCellView (in newer XCode versions it may be a Table View Cell inside a different Table View Cell). Try to bind its parent (that is to say the TableCellView, not the final NSTextFIeld inside), choosing an empty Controller Key and "objectValue.Path" as a Model Key Path